# Extracting elements from a list. ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, arraylist

Im trying to extract the numbers from a list

```
list = 'C20-H15-N5-O'
```

I have tried de following code

```
list = list.split('-')
number= [ float(i[1:]) for i in list]
```

This works as long as every atom has a number, but for the last one, 'O', is not the case and I am kinda blocked, so perhaps you could help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should the result be for the last one?

Comment: Thanks for your response! It should be '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `isnumeric()` to check if the string is a number.

```
number = [ float(i[1:]) for i in list if i[1:].isnumeric() ]
```

This will return `[20.0, 15.0, 5.0]` and ignore `O`.

You could also supply a default value for non-numeric items.

```
number = [ float(i[1:]) if i[1:].isnumeric() else 1.0 for i in list ]
```

This will return `[20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 1.0]`.

Comment: I had a typo, it should be `isnumeric`